# Why is Malwarebytes Anti-Malware reporting i.stack.imgur.com as malicious?

Tags: discussion, images

I navigated to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) this morning, and was suprised to be be greeted by a "Malicious Website Blocked" warning from Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.  It claims the malicious site in question is [i.stack.imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com).

Yesterday everything was fine. Avatars and more importantly screenshots are currently blocked. I could try to submit a screenshot, but I'm sure you see the irony there.

Was there some recent [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) hack I don't know about, or is Malwarebytes just blowing smoke?  I'm reluctant to "unblock", as this is my work computer, and I don't want it yelling at me for allowing my PC to be hacked.

Fortunately, the majority of [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) is fine, but it's a little annoying without the ability to show screenshots and the repeated warnings.

Comment: Seems like a false positive to me, but what do I know :P

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, it's just weird, and you hate to be wrong about these things.

Comment: maybe the unicorns have revolted and left malware on their way out.

Comment: There was a vulnerability on imgur : http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/09/serious-imgur-bug-exploited-to-execute-worm-like-attack-on-8chan-users/

Comment: @Leiaz Nice find!  Apparently reddit is affected too.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Malwarebytes/comments/3m1t90/blocking_imgur/  I'm thinking it'll get fixed (possibly already is?) and unblocked ASAP with hordes of angry reddit and SO users affected.

Comment: meta se dup [Malwarebytes is blocking imgur due to a zero-day exploit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266786)

Comment: @DavidPostill That question is a dupe of this one, since this one was asked an hour before.

Comment: @cybermonkey Yes but that one has more useful info ... ;)